# Cannot set sql-buffer variable from within a SQL buffer

Tags: sql-mode

I'm trying to link a SQL buffer to SQLi buffer by calling `sql-set-sqli-buffer` but nothing happens when the function is called. I'm doing this because I want to start muliple SQLi buffers with each of them having their own SQL buffer linked as instructed in `C-h f sql-interactive-mode`:

> Sample session using two connections:
>
> 1. Create first SQLi buffer by calling an entry function.
> 2. Rename buffer "*SQL*" to "*Connection 1*".
> 3. Create a SQL buffer "test1.sql".
> 4. Create second SQLi buffer by calling an entry function.
> 5. Rename buffer "*SQL*" to "*Connection 2*".
> 6. Create a SQL buffer "test2.sql".

I did exactly as described above but it doesn't work for me. The linkage is lost when the SQLi buffer is renamed to what other than *SQL*. Apparently the linkage is maintained by a local copy of the variable `sql-buffer` but the instruction above doesn't seem to reflect how this varaible is set. So I try to do this manually by calling `sql-set-sqli-buffer` and it still doesn't work.

The version currently used is Emacs 26.2.

Comment: I think there's missing information in those docs.  The `sql-mode` buffer needs to have the correct **product** set, or the link between the two buffers can't be set.  If you `M-x sql-set-product` before using `M-x sql-set-sqli-buffer` does it work?

Comment: I wrote https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlQueryBuffer to streamline this kind of thing.  Perhaps you'll find that convenient.

Comment: There may also be some bugs in 26.2 regarding changing the SQLi buffer after a rename.  I've just been testing, and this is working better in 27 than in 26.  YMMV.

Comment: TBH the example session in the `sql-interactive-mode` docstring seems misleading to me as well -- it's possible that things haven't worked quite like that for a while.  I think this is worth `M-x report-emacs-bug` -- I see `sql-buffer` set to `nil` in general, rather than being "the last SQLi  buffer created".

Comment: @phils Calling `sql-set-product` first makes it work. The SqlQueryBuffer snippet also works for me. Thanks!